# Client server communication using ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Am new to ruby
i want to run a `ruby` script in ubuntu machine.
Inside the ruby script i need to call an `exe` file from windows machine(`C:\data\file.exe`)...

How can i achieve the `client server` communication for this purpose?
or any other methods used for calling an `exe` file

Pleas esuggest any other methods also for performing this task
`ruby` code

```
  exec('C:\data\file.exe')
```

Actually in ubuntu machine am running a ruby script for doing automation using that script i have to run an exe file conatined in the windows machine.and it wil up the exe in the windows machine.i dont want any output from the windows machine to unduntu amchine

Comment: If you are on Ubuntu and would like to call a windows program that will involve setting up a server on windows which can be told to execute the program there and return the output. Why would you want to do it like this instead of just calling it through a batch file on Windows?

Comment: Actually in ubuntu machine am running a ruby script for doing automation using that script i have to run an exe file conatined in the windows machine.and it wil up the exe in the windows machine.i dont want any output from the windows machine to unduntu amchine

Comment: As I pointed out this will involve a fair bit of overhead and the system might tend to be brittle. Why do you want to spend all the work to control the Windows machine from Ubuntu instead of using a simple batch file (or ruby script for that matter) on Windows?

Comment: i want to up a firefoxe webdriver exe file in windows machine.the server machine is ubuntu.I have to send request from ubuntu to winows to up that exe.it is my project requiment.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand your setup yet, but some general pointers:

Besides

1) communication over sockets, you could

2) implement a small web-application (for example with Sinatra - if you can run ruby on your windows machine) and make the ruby script communicate with that application, by sending a http request.
Or

3) if you are running in a virtual machine setup you could touch a marker file in a shared folder and watch it from the other side.

Of course there must be many other and more involved methods (like native windows rpc calls), but I think these three ways are the quickest to learn and implement. Personally I would walk the second path, just for the fun of it.

Comment: i got what i want.http://serverfault.com/questions/521071/run-winexe-on-linux-in-order-to-exe-cli-commands-on-win-server-workgroup-serve